# ServiceStack Indie License Validity For LifeTime or for 1 Year?

Tags: servicestack

I bought indie license and do not know if it will be end completely after 1 year or only support and updates will be end and I can use for it lifetime?

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ServiceStack indie license gives you 12 months of updates and access to customer forums but will continue to work with your applications after it expires. When your license expires, you'll be limited to using the latest version of ServiceStack that was available at that time.

For full details of what you get, [see the pricing page on the ServiceStack website](https://servicestack.net/pricing).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, that was my first question and got my answer :)